# How to search data below way between two dates?

Tags: sql, mongodb, sqlite

There is a calendar. Display data after select date from calendar. Database looks like this,

```
ActivityId ActiveName SubClassificationNameSl OpenDate

1   home    100 20/09/2019 1:10:10  30/09/2019 2:02:20
2   garden  101 17/09/2019 1:10:10  25/09/2019 2:02:20
3   village 102 10/09/2019 1:10:10  21/09/2019 2:02:20
```

**If user select 27, I convert date like this,**

```
fromData = 27/09/2019 0:00:00
toDate = 27/09/2019 23:59:59
```

**When User select day, 22, Output should be, 1,2**

**When User select day, 17,
Output should be, only 2

When User select day, 20,
Output should be, 1,2,3

I tried,

```
select ActivityId,count(*) as WoCount, max(ActivityName) as ActivityName, 
       max(SubClassificationNameSl) as SubClassificationNameSl
from DetailState 
where ('27/09/2019 0:00:00' between OpenDate and CloseDate or 
       '27/09/2019 23:59:59' between OpenDate and CloseDate or
        OpenDate between '27/09/2019 0:00:00' and '27/09/2019 23:59:59' or
        CloseDate between '27/09/2019 0:00:00' and '27/09/2019 23:59:59'
      )
group by ActivityId
```

**Above code display only 27th data**

If user select 20,
data display only 1.
If user select 17,
data display only 2**

Comment: To start, you need a format for your date strings that can be meaningfully compared and ordered. The ones supported by Sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) are good choices - things like `2019-09-27 00:00:00` or `2019-09-27 23:59:59`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `between`.  I think this is the logic that you want:

```
where @from_date >= date(open_date) and
      @from_date < date(close_date, '+1 day')
```